# verify/criticise my proof of a real analysis exercise involving a limit.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, solution-verification

This is my proof of the following proposition. I would be grateful for any verification or criticism of it.

Let $f$ be integrable on $[a,b]$. For each $n\geq 1$, let

$a+\frac{(j-1)(b-a)}{n}\leq u_{jn},v_{jn}\leq a+\frac{j(b-a)}{n}$,  $1\leq j\leq n$

Then: $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}{\Big|f(u_{jn})-f(v_{jn})\Big|}=0$

$Proof:$

To simplify the notation let $x_{jn}=a+\frac{j(b-a)}{n}$, so that: $x_{(j-1)n}\leq u_{jn},v_{jn}\leq x_{jn}$.

$\space$

Then $\hspace{2mm}\Big|f(u_{jn})-f(v_{jn})\Big|\leq M_{jn}-m_{jn}\hspace{2mm}$.

Where $\hspace{2mm}M_{jn}=\sup_{t\in I_{jn}}{f(t)}\hspace{2mm}, m_{jn}=\inf_{t\in I_{jn}}{f(t)}\hspace{2mm}$ and $\hspace{2mm} I_{jn}=[x_{(j-1)n},x_{jn}]$.

$\space$

$\implies \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}{\Big|f(u_{jn})-f(v_{jn})\Big|}\leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}{(M_{jn}-m_{jn})}=\frac{1}{b-a}\sum_{j=1}^{n}{(M_{jn}-m_{jn})\frac{b-a}{n}}\hspace{20mm}(*)$

$\space$

Since $\hspace{2mm}x_{jn}-x_{(j-1)n}=\frac{b-a}{n}\hspace{2mm}, 1\leq j\leq n\hspace{2mm}$ and $\hspace{2mm}P_n=\{x_{0n},x_{1n},x_{2n},...,x_{nn}\}$ is a partition of $[a,b]$

we have:$\hspace{2mm}\sum_{j=1}^{n}{(M_{jn}-m_{jn})\frac{b-a}{n}}=S(P_n)-s(p_n)\hspace{2mm}$

where $\hspace{2mm}S(p_n)$ and $s(p_n)$ are upper and lower Riemann sums of $f$ over $P_n$

$\space$

Since $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, given $\epsilon> 0\hspace{2mm}\exists \delta>0\hspace{1mm}$ such that $\hspace{2mm} S(P_n)-s(P_n)<\epsilon(b-a)\hspace{2mm}$

if $\hspace{2mm}||P_n||<\delta$

Letting $\hspace{2mm}n>\frac{b-a}{\delta}\implies ||P_n||=\frac{b-a}{n}<\delta \implies S(p_n)-s(P_n)<\epsilon(b-a) \hspace{2mm}$

This together with $(*)$ satisfies the definition of the limit and finishes the proof. $\hspace{10mm}\square$

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Thank you, yes.